# Can we have Dark Mode?

Tags: feature-request, design

Stack Overflow just got new fancy Dark Mode https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/?cb=1

Can we have the same here?

Comment: "For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely."

Comment: @Wrigglenite that's why this is a feature request. Let's make them change their plans

Comment: I use Dark Reader on my browser, and the site looks pretty good in dark mode, so they shouldnt need to change the theme really at all to enable it imo

Comment: With our site theme supposed to be pixels+spaaaaaace, dark mode should almost be a default here. @Dragonrage Darkreader is great and what I use too. If any Dev/CM is reading this, basically implement this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en